# Why is index.html not cached offline in Angular PWA?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

When using the [Angular PWA demo](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started), I noticed the PWA does not start when the browser is offline. In that case, when opening the URL in Chrome, it shows an *offline* error.

Looking in Chrome DevTools, it appears that `index.html`is not stored in the cache:

[image: index.html is missing in the cache]

The strange thing though, is that `index.html`  actually **is**  configured to be cached:

[image: index.html is configured to be cached]

So I guess some configuratio is missing, to make the PWA startable offline. Concretely, how can `index.html`be included in the urls list in the generated file `ngsw.json`?

Btw, I tried to add `index.html` to the assets list in `angular.json`, this fixes the caching part but it results in no longer adding the script tags for the Angular runtime.